# Obter dois valores de uma string

Tags: string, vb.net

Estou criando uma linguagem de programação e para você definir variáveis nela você usa esse código:

```
def NomeDaVariavel = ValorDela;
```

E queria saber como eu pego apenas o campo `Nome da variável`, separado do `ValorDela`.

Alguma ideia? Obrigado.

**Atualização**

```
If (Regex.IsMatch(currentText, "^\s*(def)")) Then
   Dim tempProvider As Match = Regex.Match(currentText, "^\s*def.*[^=]=")
   Dim nomeDaVariavel As String = tempProvider.Value.Substring(
              currentText.IndexOf("def") + Iff(currentText.Trim() = " = ", 4, 3)).Replace("=", "").Replace(" ", "")
   Dim valorDaVariavel As String = ParseStr(currentText)
   MsgBox(FX("A Variável '\0' tem o valor de '\1'.", nomeDaVariavel, valorDaVariavel))
   Continue For
End If
```

Isso funcionou, pois eu testei assim:

```
def testando = 'Olá, mundo!';
```

E funcionou! Fica a dica ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode-se usar o [método `String.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para extrair parte do texto.

```
Dim texto As String = "def NomeDaVariavel = ValorDela;"

Dim indiceVar As Integer = texto.IndexOf("def")
Dim indiceVal As Integer = texto.IndexOf("=")

Dim tamanhoVar As Integer = Len(indiceVar)

Dim varNome As String = texto.Substring(indiceVar + tamanhoVar, texto.IndexOf("=") - tamanhoVar - 1)
Dim varVal As String = texto.Substring(indiceVal + 2, texto.IndexOf(";") - indiceVal - 2)

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", varNome, varVal))
Console.ReadKey()
```

Se for necessário obter cada palavra, use o [método `String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim texto As String = "def NomeDaVariavel = ValorDela;"

Dim palavras As String() = texto.Split(New Char() {" "})
Dim palavra As String
For Each palavra In palavras
    Console.WriteLine(palavra)
Next
Console.ReadKey()
```

<kbd>[**`Exemplo`**](http://ideone.com/utiQBn)</kbd>

Comment: Gostei dese método, mas ai só ta o nome dela, e o valor?

Comment: @CypherPotato Já adicionei.